# Bayesian Neural Network in timeseries

Tags: time-series, bayesian, neural-networks, bayesian-network, pymc

I am currently exploring Bayesian Neural Network application on timeseries and stumbled on pymc3 library. But don't exactly understand how can I use it on a timeseries data.

I am coming from a background of using statistical models:ARIMA, GARCH on timeseries.

To start I want to implement a simple Bayesian feed-forward neural network on a timeseries data.

What I am thinking to do is to set AR & MA values of a univariate timeseries as the priors for my model.Therefore analyze their distribution to build my posterior.

Could someone guide is it logical to start this way?

Answer (score 2):

Usually there are two ways to model time-series in Deep Learning:

1. Recurrent Neural Networks like LSTM (there are many resources if you google). You should be able to implement those in PyMC3, especially if they are supported by Lasagne.
2. Placing a stochastic process like random-walk or ARMA on the parameters of your neural network. See my blog post for more info: http://twiecki.github.io/blog/2017/03/14/random-walk-deep-net/